# Is there any point in using vendor specific prefixes other than "-webkit-" for "transition"?

Tags: css, css-transitions, vendor-prefix

In the course I'm taking, I found the following (excerpt):

```
p.box{
-webkit-transition: border-radius 1s;
-moz-transition: border-radius 1s;
-o-transition: border-radius 1s;
-ms-transition: border-radius 1s;
transition: border-radius 1s;
}

p.rounded{
border-radius:50px;
}
```

However, according to [this table](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-transitions), there seems to be no point in using other browser specific prefixes than `-webkit-`. The newer versions of IE, FireFox and Opera always support this property and the older versions never do. So it seems to me that the lines starting with `-moz-`, `-o-` and `-ms-` will in no case whatsoever affect page display. Can I -from now on- always leave these out in the case of `transition`? Or am I misunderstanding something? Or is the table incorrect?

Comment: Not te answer to your questin, but for vendor prefix trounble you can use prefix-free.js

Comment: @Florija: do you mean adding such CSS with jQuery for instance? In my course they just told me that anything you can do in CSS without Javascript is better done without it since "pure" CSS performs better. That's actually how I ended up with this question in the first place.

Comment: I do agree that you should write short pure CSS, but for me personally, it's a hassle to add all vendor prefixes for gradients, animations and styles (especially for older browsers).

Answer (score 2):

Firefox until v15 requires the `-moz` prefix and Opera the `-o` until v12 (the `-ms` prefix is, in this instance, pointless)<sup>*</sup>. So, you're correct in saying that you could remove those prefixes and not see any difference in the *latest versions* of all browsers. However, you might find that those slightly older versions still make up a significant number of visitors to any particular site.

I'd recommend including the prefixes until the versions of browsers that require them are well and truly in the past. That way, you know that they will only account for a tiny minority of your visitors. As an example, it's no longer worth including the prefixes for `border-radius`: Firefox supports the non-prefixed version all the way back to v3.6, and Chrome from v4.

You could use something like [Compass](http://compass-style.org/) or [Prefix free](http://leaverou.github.com/prefixfree/) (if either fits into your workflow) to take care of this for you.

**Edit** - I don't personally make use of Prefix-free, as I share the OP's hesitance at creating styling with JavaScript where it's not strictly necessary. If SASS/Compass isn't an option, I recommend [the Prefixr plugin](http://wbond.net/sublime_packages/prefixr) for Sublime Text. That way, you only have to worry about writing the non-prefixed version by hand, but you're still sending a fully prefixed-up version in your stylesheet.

* These stats come from [CanIUse...](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-transitions), you just need to click the link at the top left of the compatibility table that says 'Show all versions' to see information about all browsers.

Comment: thanks for contributing! But where did you get that info? The [table I linked to](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-transitions) doesn't mention any use for the `-moz-` or `-o-` extensions. And don't you worry that Prefix free may slow down the rendering of your page more than circumventing vendor-specific CSS by using jQuery?

Comment: cool, I missed the "all versions" link! But I don't  see why you would like to refrain from Javascript for style where not strictly necessary. To me (as a novice) it seems very readable, short code and very powerful and flexible too. I wouldn't expect a huge drop in performance and only a (very) tiny minority of the online population use a Javascript disabled browser, right?

Comment: Because we have a tool for styling: CSS. It may be only a minority of users without JavaScript, but what if they're on a slow connection and it takes a few seconds to download jQuery? That's an unnecessary flash of semi-styled content (FoSSC!?). I don't disagree that in this instance there are good arguments for it, I just prefer to keep styling from JS unless *absolutely* necessary, so I prefer those tools (linked above) that solve the problem but ensure that the stylesheet itself contains the styling.